# How to prevent ndb from batching a put_async() call and make it issue the RPC immediately?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a request handler that updates an entity, saves it to the datastore, then needs to perform some additional work before returning (like queuing a background task and json-serializing some results). I want to parallelize this code, so that the additional work is done while the entity is being saved.

Here's what my handler code boils down to:

```py
class FooHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.toplevel
    def post(self):
        foo = yield Foo.get_by_id_async(some_id)

        # Do some work with foo

        # Don't yield, as I want to perform the code that follows
        # while foo is being saved to the datastore.
        # I'm in a toplevel, so the handler will not exit as long as
        # this async request is not finished.
        foo.put_async()

        taskqueue.add(...)
        json_result = generate_result()
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        self.response.write(json_result)
```

However, Appstats shows that the `datastore.Put` RPC is being done serially, after `taskqueue.Add`:

[image: Appstats screenshot]

A little digging around in `ndb.context.py` shows that a `put_async()` call ends up being added to an `AutoBatcher` instead of the RPC being issued immediately.

So I presume that the `_put_batcher` ends up being flushed when the `toplevel` waits for all async calls to be complete.

I understand that batching puts has real benefits in certain scenarios, but in my case here I really want the put RPC to be sent immediately, so I can perform other work while the entity is being saved.

If I do `yield foo.put_async()`, then I get the same waterfall in Appstats, but with `datastore.Put` being done before the rest:

[image: 2nd Appstats screenshot]

This is to be expected, as `yield` makes my handler wait for the `put_async()` call to complete before executing the rest of the code.

I also have tried adding a call to `ndb.get_context().flush()` right after `foo.put_async()`, but the `datastore.Put` and `taskqueue.BulkAdd` calls are still not being made in parallel according to Appstats.

So my question is: how can I force the call to `put_async()` to bypass the auto batcher and issue the RPC immediately?

Comment: Is it on production or local?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no supported way to do it. Maybe there should be. Can you try if this works?

```
loop - ndb.eventloop.get_event_loop()
while loop.run_idle():
    pass
```

You may have to look at the source code of ndb/eventloop.py to see what else you could try -- basically you want to try most of what run0() does except waiting for RPCs.  In particular, it's possible that you would have to do this:

```
while loop.current:
    loop.run0()
while loop.run_idle():
    pass
```

(This still isn't supported, because there are other conditions you may have to handle too, but those don't seem to occur in your example.)

Comment: I got it to work by calling `ndb.get_context().flush()` followed by the 2 loops you suggested right after my call to `foo.put_async()`. I believe there should be an officially supported way to do this, as I don't think my usage scenario is uncommon (save an entity, then wrap-up remaining handler work while entity is being saved). I filed a feature request for it: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8863

Comment: I think what is really needed is taskqueue.add_async to get the task queue rpc into the idle/rpc loops in eventloop. http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=180

Comment: What exactly was the code that worked for you? flush() is a tasklet so you would have to yield it, possibly causing more delay than you'd like. Anyways, agreed this would be a useful feature. Perhaps it'll get more attention if you file it in the NDB tracker?

Comment: If put includes a memcache set as well, run_idle will set up the memcache rpc only, not the datastore rpc. Datastore rpc would execute after taskqueue add.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum, I had edited your answer with details about what had worked for me, but the edit didn't get approved for some reasons... Like I said in a previous comment: calling `flush()` then doing the 2 loops you suggested.

Comment: And I did file a feature request (I provided the link in a previous comment).

Comment: @tesdal I agree about taskqueue needing an async API. I had already starred this feature request. As for your memcache comment: in my case, the entity being saved asynchronously is not using memcache (I disabled the memcache policy for that Model).

Answer (score -2):

Try this, I'm not 100% certain it will help:

```
foo = yield Foo.get_by_id_async(some_id)
future = foo.put_async()
future.done()
```

ndb requests get put into the autobatcher, the batch gets sent to RPC when you need a result.  Since you don't need the result of foo.put_async(), it doesn't get sent until you make another ndb call (you don't) or until the @ndb.toplevel ends.

Calling future.done() does not block, but I'm guessing it might trigger the request.

Another thing to try to force the operation is:

```
ndb.get_context().flush()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do anything. `Future.done()` only does `return self._done` without any processing, and I had already tried `Context.flush()`.